# How to install ckeditor uploader

Tags: ckeditor, uploader

How to install ckeditor uploader ?

[uploader like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9JeS.png)

Comment: The same question asked in Google has the correct answer in the first few posts. Perhaps if you asked why <insert method here> gave you a problem, we could at least see what you had tried.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is JavaScript application which doesn't upload files by itself. You need a file uploader like [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/#ckfinder) (not free), [custom file uploader](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/search/plugins/upload) or your own uploader.

Please also see docs for more details:
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload